# Concatenate Specific DataFrames from List (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, split

There is a DataFrame of 16 samples which I would like to break into chunks of 4 dataframes. For the first iteration of the code, the test set is the first index and the rest are testing. The following iteration, the second is the test and all others are used for training, and so on.

The error is in line 5 with this simple code in which

Code attempted:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(16, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
split_lst = np.array_split(df, 4)
for j in range(0, 4):
     test = split_lst[j]
     train = pd.concat([split_lst[:j] , split_lst[j+1:]]) **# error here**
     print(test)
     print(train)
```

Error is:
(<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError("cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"), <traceback object at 0x0000012A66F8F1C0>)

Comment: why you put `split_lst[:j] + split_lst[j+1:]`  in `[]`?

Comment: was trying to follow the 'frames' and 'concat' example here:https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: `split_lst[:j] + split_lst[j+1:]` is already a list, no need to wrap it in a list. Remove the outer list and will work fine, so like: `pd.concat(split_lst[:j] , split_lst[j+1:])`

Comment: Hmm just tried it but getting an error (<class 'ValueError'>, ValueError('No objects to concatenate'), <traceback object at 0x0000021609EFD4C0>)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, you can use drop method to remove one column in test. And I think your test is wrong. I would right the code as

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(16, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
split_lst = np.array_split(df, 4)
for j in range(0, 4):
     df_temp = split_lst[j]
     test = df_temp.iloc[:,j]
     train = df_temp.drop(df.columns[j], axis=1)
     print(test)
     print(train)
```